# Setting domain cookies troubles

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, httpresponse

I'm trying to set cookie's domain. But it's not working, my cookie is not created after this:

```
    javax.servlet.http.Cookie responseCookie =
        new Cookie(startpackCookie.getName(),
                   startpackCookie.getValue());

    responseCookie.setMaxAge(startpackCookie.getMaxAge());
    responseCookie.setPath(startpackCookie.getPath());
    responseCookie.setDomain(startpackCookie.getDomain());

    System.out.println("Cookie max age: " +
                       responseCookie.getMaxAge());
    System.out.println("Cookie path: " + responseCookie.getPath());
    System.out.println("Cookie domain: " + responseCookie.getDomain());
    response.addCookie(responseCookie);
```

Output:

```
10:28:34,899 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Cookie max age: -1
10:28:34,900 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Cookie path: /
10:28:34,900 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Cookie domain: playground.startpack.ru
10:28:34,901 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Cookie was sended
```

If I will delete domain settings, it will work with `localhost` domain. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Sun's site ,
"By default, cookies are only returned to the host which saved them."

http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.1/api/javax.servlet.http.Cookie.html#setDomain(javax.servlet.http.String)

Also a domain name name begins with a dot (".foo.com") visible to servers in a specified Domain Name System (DNS) zone (for example, www.foo.com, but not a.b.foo.com)

Comment: Do you mean that `setDomain` haven't got any sense?